# Powershell passing variable to netsh command

Tags: powershell

how do I pass the value of `$ethernet` to replace "Ethernet 5"

```
$ethernet=(Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex $(Get-NetConnectionProfile | ? IPv4Connectivity -eq "Internet").InterfaceIndex)[0].Name | Out-String

netsh interface ipv4 set dns "Ethernet 5" static 10.79.0.2
```

tried this and doesn't work

```
netsh interface ipv4 set dns $ethernet static 10.79.0.2
```

Comment: Can you try `& "netsh interface ipv4 set dns $ethernet static 10.79.0.2"`

Comment: I would renove the `|Out-Stting` as it will probably add a trailing space. (Instead, if you not sure if it concerns a string, add `.ToString()` or use double quotes: `"$Ethernet"`)